# RAD Studio XE2 - Obtain procedure names

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I was wondering if there was a way to get a list of all the procedure and function names which I have written myself, for my Delphi application?
 I need to be able to copy and paste these into a word document.

Comment: You can extract this information from the .map file generated by the linker. But you'll need to process it into a readable form.

Comment: Try the free [`Document Insight Express`](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/documentation-insight/feature-matrix/) version that comes with Delphi.

Comment: You could write a program which takes as input the .pas files of your project. Such a program would be looking for lines which begin 'Procedure' or 'Function'.

Comment: @No'am Why would the lines have to begin with those words? What about commented out code? Class functions? Strangely indented code? Include files?

Comment: GExperts has a tool called ProcedureList that shows all procedures and functions in the project.  This list can be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Creating a word document is a silly step because it will become out of sync with the real application very soon, and will not be that useful a source of information. Writing comments in the code that are in the form that Document Insight Express can use to extract documentation, in a manner similar to javadoc, is preferable, and these "documents" can be regenerated when desired, and then if you like, processed through stylesheets and turned into help or API documentation.
tutorial: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42394

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't mean lines whose first nine characters are 'procedure', but rather lines which contain the string 'procedure'. Such a parsing program (one could hijack a 'pretty print program) would automatically skip over whitespace and comments anyway.

Comment: @LURD Thanks, but Doc Insight is a bit fiddly and it only shows the procedures which I have declared at the top of my form.

Comment: @Bill GExperts is great! It gets every procedure name for me and it has a load of other stuff too. It copies straight to the clipboard just as you said

Comment: @WarrenP I'll have a look at the link you posted, but I need these names for a particular purpose. Nothing to do with documenting code for future reference.

Comment: If you need to be able to extract these names not just once, but on demand in the future, you might investigate using RTTI to do it, if all the procedures were methods instead, for instance, class methods.